# What is Android SDK Add-ons?

Tags: android, sdk, android-source

I have read that if someone wants to deploy their own library in the custom firmware then they need to provide a sdk add-on.

> what is sdk add-on and its purpose ?
>
> Can I build my own sdk add-on ?

I have googled it but didn't find any information about it.